# unable to stop php looping function

Tags: php

I'm creating a function using php to get data using php://input.

Here is an example code:

```
    function check_data() {
        $data = (object) get_data();
        $id = $data->id;
    
        $text = $data->text;
        switch ($text){
            case 'on':
                turn_on();
                app_play($id);
                break;
            case 'off':
                turn_off();
                return false;
    
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    
    function app_play($id){
        $is_on = get_status();
    
        if($is_on){
            send_data();
            sleep(10);
            check_data();
        }
    }
    check_data();
```

the problem is the process cannot stop and continues to send data even after a "turn off" command has been sent.

how to stop looping like that?

Comment: look i know its a crappy answer, but have you tried to add "DIE" after the return.

Comment: You might be better off with a do/while loop rather than this type of nested/recursive functions.

Comment: why downvoted? the question is just how to stop php looping like that

Comment: @Scuzzy I need to keep checking the command to send data again, can you give me example using do/while loop for this case?

Comment: @ZappsCeo it's not work

Comment: Can you explain what you are intending to achieve? Are you expecting the loop to exit if you receive the OFF command?

Comment: @IbnulHusainan review https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php basically you want to test "whilst on, keep doing the work"

Comment: @TimBrownlaw the workflow is like this:

when I send the command turn_on () it will send data repeatedly with a certain delay (there I use the sleep () function). then if I send the command turn_off () then it will stop the data sending process and if I send the command turn_on () again it will continue sending the data.

Comment: Where is get_data() actually getting its data from? Does turn_off actually set a global variable $is_on to false?

Comment: @kojow7 trun_on() and trun_off() function is just to set update value to my config database, so $is_on = get_status(); is result of query to check config status like "select status from config where ........"

Comment: all functions are working properly. it's just that I don't know how to temporarily stop the process until I order it to run again.

Comment: @IbnulHusainan Without seeing more of your working code, it is hard to know what you are doing. Can you export a message to a log file to verify `$is_on` actually does turn false? Do you need to call get_status() inside of your loop? Can you change your loop to say: `$is_on = check_data()`. You are returning false, but not doing anything with that false value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution to get out of the loop, apparently I found no solution except creating a loop using cronjob.